# Enter export password to generate a P12 certificate

Tags: command-line, passwords, openssl

I would like to generate a P12 certificate from a .key and .pem.
I'm running this command and get prompted to enter a export password:

```
pkcs12 -export -inkey private-key.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12
```

[image]

I can't enter a password at this point, it seems that the keyboard input is not recognized.

What do I miss? (I'm new to the Command Line tool and openSSL)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

OpenSSL command line app does not display any characters when you are entering your password. Just type it then press enter and you will see that it is working.

You can also use `openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12 -password pass:YourPassword` to pass the password `YourPassword` from command line. Please take a look at section [Pass Phrase Options](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl.html#Pass-Phrase-Options) in OpenSSL manual for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Can a password be added directly through the openSSL command btw? Is this a correct command line for it? `pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12 -p 123example`

Comment: For me, openssl's password input is a little screwy. It asks me for the password and does not show anything, as expected. But I have to press enter twice. I enter the same password for verification, and it will not work. I also found out that if I press enter once and then enter the password, it will show it on my screen. Pressing enter a second time will move onto the verification. I type the same password in the same manner and... it doesn't work! I'm putting the password into the parameter.

Comment: Is it `-password` or `-passout`?

Comment: With -export, -password is equivalent to -passout.  Otherwise, -password is equivalent to -passin.

Answer (score 25):

I know this thread has been idle for a while, but I just wanted to add my two cents to supplement jariq's comment...

Per manual, you don't necessary want to use `-password` option.

Let's say `mykey.key` has a password and your want to protect `iphone-dev.p12` with another password, this is what you'd use:

```
pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out iphone_dev.p12 -passin pass:password_for_mykey -passout pass:password_for_iphone_dev
```

Have fun scripting!!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! You know if passin/passout is version specific?

Answer (score 10):

The selected answer apparently does not work anymore in 2019 (at least for me).

I was trying to export a certificate using openssl (version 1.1.0) and the parameter `-password` doesn't work.

According to [that link](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/openssl.html#Pass-Phrase-Options) in the original answer (the same info is in `man openssl`), openssl has two parameter for passwords and they are `-passin` for the input parts and `-passout` for output files.

For the `-export` command, I used `-passin` for the password of my key file and `-passout` to create a new password for my P12 file.

So the complete command without any prompt was like below:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in /tmp/MyCert.crt -inkey /tmp/MyKey.key -out /tmp/MyP12.p12 -name alias -passin pass:keypassphrase -passout pass:certificatepassword
```

If you does not want a password, you can use `pass:` like below:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in /tmp/MyCert.crt -inkey /tmp/MyKey.key -out /tmp/MyP12.p12 -name alias -passin pass: -passout pass:
```

It will works fine with a key without password and the output certificate will be created without password too.

Answer (score 4):

MacOS High Sierra is very crazy to update openssl command suddenly.

Possible in last month:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
MAC verified OK
```

But now:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts -password pass:
MAC verified OK
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this "MAC verified OK" at all ?